# python socket can not read the pic

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

a strange question.i can see about text_content. but i can't see pic_content,i don't know why. use chrome have a fault."Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:" and  i discover maybe my if else codes does not work.pic must be image/jpg can output..but i don't know why and how to do ...

```
import socket
#Address
#httpq server

HOST = ''
PORT = 8000

#prepare HTTP response

#start line head and body
text_content = '''HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
<html>
<head>
<title>WOW</titile>
</head>

<p>WOW,python server</p>
<img src="test.jpg/">
</html>
'''

#read picture ,put into HTTP format
f = open('test.jpg','rb')
pic_content = '''
HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpg
'''
pic_content = pic_content + f.read()
f.close()

#cofigure socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
#infinite loop,server forever
while True:
    #3:maxinum number of requests waitting
    s.listen(3)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    request = conn.recv(1024)
    method = request.split(' ')[0]
    src    = request.split(' ')[1]

    #deal with GET method
    if method =='GET':
        #URL
        if src =='/test.jpg':
            content = pic_content
        else:content = text_content

        print 'Connected by',addr
        print 'Request is:', request
        conn.sendall(content)
    #close connection
    conn.close()
```

Comment: import socket .. please append to first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing blank lines between the HTTP header and the body (after `Content-Type`).

Since you are already logging the request, you can see that the browser is requesting `test.jpg/` with an extraneous trailing slash. Remove it, and it works.

Comment: thanks .i solved the problem.. focus it should be  <img src="test.jpg"/> and after Content-Type: image/jpg should have a new line   oh a mistake....takes me so much time ... and this you again XD